# Shiny with jquery UI

Tags: javascript, r, jquery-ui, shiny

I want to use jquery UI with shiny (not using shinyjqui library). It works perfect when I have a layer and tried to move it using jqueryUI, but when this layer is dynamically generated using insertUI, then, it doesn´t work.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = "style.css",
            tags$script(src = "jquery-ui.js"),
            tags$script(src = "script2.js"),
            actionButton("add","Add layer"),
            div(class="aux"),
            div(id="works",style="width:300px;height:200px;background:red"))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$add,{
    insertUI(
      selector = ".aux",
      where="afterEnd",
      ui  = div(id=paste0("new",input$add),style="width:300px;height:200px;background:blue")

    )


  })






}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the js script

```
  $( function() {


    $("#works").draggable();
    $("#new1").draggable();


  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `#new1` does not exist at the start-up. You have to execute the javascript code after it have been created, with `shinyjs::runjs` for example. And use `immediate=TRUE` in `insertUI`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"),
    tags$script("$(function() {
                    $('#works').draggable();
                })")
  ),
  actionButton("add","Add layer"),
  div(class="aux"),
  div(id="works",style="width:300px;height:200px;background:red"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    insertUI(
      selector = ".aux",
      where="afterEnd",
      ui = div(id=paste0("new",input$add), style="width:300px;height:200px;background:blue"),
      immediate = TRUE
    )
    runjs("$('#new1').draggable();")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. Perhaps something has changed.

Comment: @GiovanniColitti did you download the jquery ui library and place it in the same directory as your shiny app? also you can do 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js' as the src in the first `tags$script()` instead of 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'.